# What are some use cases for tuple structs?

Tags: rust, types

The Rust book mentions that "it is almost always better to use a struct than a tuple struct." Other than the newtype pattern, are there any other advantages of having unnamed fields? Seems to me like the newtype pattern is the only useful case of having tuple structs.

Comment: Another use case is mathematical vectors of small arity. Like in a 2d or 3d vector processing library. Although you could also use a newtype for an array there.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

They are very similar to each other.

Given the following [definitions](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a9d18a3f96af6f8a063bc6d404857eb7&version=stable&backtrace=0):

```
struct TupleStruct(i32, i32);
struct NormalStruct {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
}
```

We construct instances of structs and tuple structs as follows:

```
let ts = TupleStruct(1, 2);
let ns = NormalStruct { a: 1, b: 2 };

// shortcut to initialize the fields of a struct using the values of the
// fields of another struct
let ns2 = NormalStruct { a: 5, ..ns };
let ts2 = TupleStruct { 0: 1, ..ts }; // for TupleStruct it needs curly brackets
                                      // and implicit field names
```

Assignments work as follows:

```
let TupleStruct(x, y) = ts;
println!("x: {}, y: {}", x, y);

let NormalStruct { a, b } = ns;
println!("a: {}, b: {}", a, b);
```

Access a *tuple struct*'s fields using implicit names (0, 1, ...):

```
println!("Accessing ts by name - {}{}", ts.0, ts.1);
println!("Accessing ns by name - {}{}", ns.a, ns.b);
```

For documentation purposes, it's almost always clearer to assign explicit names to the fields of the struct. That's why, in the Rust community, I've seen many argue for always using a normal struct.

However, there might be cases where the fields of the struct are inherently "anonymous", one notable case being the "newtype" (tuple struct with one field) serving only to wrap an inner type.

In that case, naming the inner field does not arguably provide any additional information, e.g.:

```
struct Inches {
    inner: i32,
}
```

vs

```
struct Inches(i32);
```

The [section on structs on the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#using-the-newtype-pattern-for-type-safety-and-abstraction) has more info on newtypes.

Comment: Thx. What's the preference for `type Args = (i32, i32)` vs. `struct Args(i32, i32)`?

Comment: @HelinWang those are two different things. With `type` you define an alias (you create a different name for the same thing) and you can use one in any place you would use the other. See [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=617deb82495d71f83e54e36dbc11cdf7)

Comment: Is there any significant difference in memory usage and allocation, beyond one stores field names? Or are they just two different ways to implement the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

- Named structs provide clarity by explicitly naming each field, making it easier to understand the purpose of each component. Tuple structs are often shorter and more concise than named structs, making them suitable for simple wrapper types. For this purpose `rust-rocket` web framework package uses `tuple structs`

  ```
  #[derive(rocket_db_pools::Database)]
  // this will look for env variables starts with postgres and will pass it to PgPool

  #[database("postgres")]
  pub struct DbConnection(rocket_db_pools::diesel::PgPool);
  ```

In general tuple-like syntax can be convenient for types that don't require named fields.

- Semantic Grouping when we represent RGB color values

  ```
  struct Rgb(u8, u8, u8);
  ```

in this case, the individual fields don't have meaningful names, the struct is meant to be used as a container for a fixed set of values.

- Type alias for a 2D point using a tuple struct

  ```
   struct Point(f64, f64);

  let origin = Point(0.0, 0.0);

  // Access fields of the tuple struct
  println!("x: {}, y: {}", origin.0, origin.1);
  ```
- tuple struct to create a new type for a single value

  ```
  struct Millimeters(u32);

  fn print_length(length: Millimeters) {
      println!("Length: {} millimeters", length.0);
  }
  ```

Comment: hank you for pointing out the typo